# Rank of a Matrix inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is this inequality true for a matrix $rk(A) \le rk(A | B)  $ for a matrix ?I know that rk(A) means all rows that are not zero ,but what does rk(A | B) mean?

Comment: (A|B) is an [augmented matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix), one with additional columns on the right. And [rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) is not the non-zero rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rank of a matrix is the number of nonzero rows when you reduce it to row echelon form using Gaussian elimination. So rank of $(A|B)$ is the number of nonzero rows of the row echelon form of the extended matrix $(A|B)$ where you just put $A$ and $B$ together as a bigger matrix, with number of columns the sum of columns of $A$ and $B$.

For example,

\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Then $A$ can be reduced to 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$(A|B)$ can be reduced to

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So rank of $A$ is 2, rank of $(A|B)$ is 3.

Comment: and if we had -1 in the last matrix the rank of (A|B) would be 2 right?

Comment: Do you mean if we had $-1$ in the original $B$? No, we have to have $1$ in the original $B$ so that the rank of $(A|B)$ is 2.

Comment: last matrix 3x4 if all were 0 0 0 0

Comment: Yes, if they are all zeros, then the rank of $(A|B)$ is 2.